# Закончилось место в разделе /boot, заходит только в GRUB, что делать?

Tags: ubuntu

Стала ставить обновления на убунту, выскочило сообщение о том что закончилось место в разделе boot, а через несколько секунд экран погас и сейчас при включении заходит только в GRUB. Загрузилась с LiveCD, боюсь сделать что-то не так, так как на компьютере очень много работы и информации.

Подскажите, пожалуйста порядок действий.
Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: [восстановление grub](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_grub). для этого сначала понадобится хоть немного свободного места на разделе. скорее всего, у вас установлено несколько версий linux. удалите наиболее старую (ориентироваться можно на номер версии или на дату создания файлов). это пара файлов: `vmlinuz-версия` и `initrd.img-версия`

Answer (score 1):

если дело только в свободном месте то этого должно хватить:

как размечен жесткий диск ?

`sudo fdisk -l`

/, /home на одном разделе или на разных?

`sudo cat /etc/fstab`

покажет какой каталог сколько занимает.

```
`sudo du -shc /*`
```

покажет сколько занимает каталог .cache/ в Вашем домашнем каталоге, оттуда можно все удалить.

`du -shc /home/<ваш логин>/.cache/*`

может, место закончилось не в /boot а в /? если так то попереписывать часть информации куда-то на флешку, стереть то что не нужно. можно очистить /var/cashe/apt/. в общем, освободить место на жестком диске.

сразу добавка: на всякий случай проверить жесткий диск на ошибки (но можно и пропустить)

`fsck -y /dev/sd*`

(звездочка - буква устройства жесткого диска. детали - вывод `sudo cat /etc/fstab`)

Comment: когда ввожу sudo fdisk -l, сразу вижу:
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted. Дальше слишком много символов, на 1500 превышен лимит.
Еще вижу свой жесткий диск с файлами слева на панели, но как на него зайти и сделать бекап не могу понять.

Comment: @bizzzz1 предупреждение о том что используется GPT,  говорит нужно использовать графическую софтинку  GNU Parted (gparted), должна быть на LiveCD. я бы проигнорировал это предупреждение (это не критическая ошибка)

Comment: Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes | 

| Disk /dev/sdb: 8074 MB, 8074035200 bytes |
   Вот это я так понимаю мой жесткий диск со всеми файлами, каждый из разделов заканчивается фразой "Disk doesn't contain a valid partition table."  
| Disk /dev/mapper/luks-da24f799-6c64-431a-a74a-86a9e4434332: 999.4 GB, 999408271360 bytes |

| Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 990.9 GB, 990883348480 bytes

 | Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 8514 MB, 8514437120 bytes

Comment: @bizzzz1 тут (в комментариях) не получится все решить. прочитайте еще то что alexander barakin про GRUB прокомментировал. попробуйте место освободить и перезагрузиться или подключить какой-то жесткий диск c ubuntu, оттуда проверить что с данными. или поищите среди знакомых знакомого линуксоида